# Angular Materials flex box model not apply correctly

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am working with angualar and angular material and I am trying to create something linke this -> http://gyazo.com/51b99edb716687f6096e4cff7d009e8d

but for some reason my image (logo) stretches over de width, this is what I have now -> http://gyazo.com/277f2bcf6b47861412d8e5df949d8313
I can't even seem to get it in the middle of the screen

If any one can help me out and get me going with this flex box model I would appreciate it

this is my code:

```
<div layout="row" flex layout-padding layout-fill layout-align="center center">
    <div flex="40" flex-lg="50" flex-md="70" flex-sm="100">
        <md-card>
            <md-toolbar>
                <div>
                    <div><img src="../images/logo.png" alt="Zazzle logo"></div>
                    <h1 class="md-headline">
                    Sign up 
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </md-toolbar>
        </md-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To center something add a `div` with `layout="row"` and within the div add a `<span flex></span>` before and after the `div` you are trying to center.

This is how I do it for my login page to center the input divs. I am still trying to learn myself, so I am not sure if it is the right way or not but you can surely try it:

```
<div layout="row">
    <span flex></span>
    <div class="well" flex='30'>
        <form ng-submit="vm.login()" name="loginForm">
            <md-input-container>
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="vm.email" required/>
                <div ng-messages="loginForm.email.$error" ng-if='loginForm.email.$dirty'>
                    <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
                </div>
            </md-input-container>
            <md-input-container>
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" ng-model="vm.password"/>
            </md-input-container>
            <md-button type="submit" class="md-raised md-primary">Submit</md-button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <span flex></span>
</div>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: mmm for me it does not seem to work ->http://gyazo.com/7de91b6b9aaf450b76590610b0940bf6

Comment: This link explains how they are arranged based on layout and how you can modify the positioning https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/layout/options